# How do you get a number formatter into a react-google-charts chart? (sorry; newb in react)

Tags: javascript, charts

I can get a formatter injected into a google chart to format multiple columns with code like this:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: '$' });
formatter.format(dataTable, 1);
formatter.format(dataTable, 2);
```

I've tried setting "numberFormat:" and "formatters: []" in the react-google-charts options but they don't seem to work.  Does anyone have an example?

Update:

This works to set the format of a single column:

```
<Chart
    chartType="ColumnChart"
    rows={rows}
    columns= {columns}
    width='100%'
    numberFormat={{column: 1, options: {fractionDigits: 2, prefix: '$'}}}
    ....
/>
```

This does not:

```
<Chart
    chartType="ColumnChart"
    rows={rows}
    columns= {columns}
    width='100%'
    formatters={[{type: 'NumberFormat', 
                  column: 1, 
                  options: {fractionDigits: 2, prefix: '$'}]}
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Solved: formatters[] code is not yet in the released version of react-google-charts.

Answer (score 1):

Please following see the following
https://react-google-charts.com/formatters#numberformat

```
formatters={[
   {
      type: "NumberFormat",
      column: 1,
      options: {
         prefix: "$",
         suffix: "%",
         negativeColor: "red",
         negativeParens: true,
       }
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the formatters[] code is not in the current release.  D'oh

Answer (score 0):

I needed to format the Yaxis label to use currency options
The formatters didn't work for me (I use React & Google charts for react) a well

The Only thing that worked, is adding the bAxes format to the main options for my Chart

```
const options = {
      title: 'USD',
      height: 500,
      pointSize: 5,
      vAxes: {
        0: { title: 'primary', format: 'currency' },
        1: { title: 'secondary' },
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'none',
      },
    };
```

[image]