# Format All Data in React Google Charts API

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization, react-google-charts

Using Google Charts in React, I have 4 stacked values in each column adding up to 100 (percent).

I want the value displayed when hovering over each part to be rounded to the nearest tenths place.

I *must* do this without changing the values with which the chart is generated.

I am using react-google-charts version 3.0.15.

Thanks!

Comment: [How do you get a number formatter into a react-google-charts chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48745910/5090771)

Comment: Thanks, I was referencing that before asking my question. Unfortunately it was not working for me, and it still wouldn't quite solve my problem - I'd like all values in all columns to be rounded, without having to specify which column.